# How to display an HTML page from raw folder in res with android Webview?

Tags: android, resources, webview

I have a web page stored in my res/raw folder in android app. I want to access it and load it in the webview in my activity. Can anyone please tell me how am I supposed to do that. 
I have tried

```
webView.loadUrl(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myHtmlPage).toString());
```

but it dint work rather it gives a broken page.

kindly help me out.

regards
FAS

Comment: assets/ can not be translated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load html files from raw folder in web view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171316/load-html-files-from-raw-folder-in-web-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you have the raw html as a string such as `"<html>...</html>"`?

If so then `Webview.loadData()` or `Webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl()` should work.