# Load html files from raw folder in web view

Tags: android, android-webview

How to load `html` files in `WebView` from `raw` folder. I don't know how to add the path of these `html` files in `WebView.loadData()` function. I know how to load file from `asset` folder in `WebView` but here getting problem with `raw` folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3152441/