# where to place the html,java script files other than assets in android

Tags: android, webview, hybrid

can we add the html and java script code anywhere other than assets folder in android which will used in web View, and it cannot be a URL also since it should work offline, because when we place the .html,java script etc in assets it can be easily found when we unzip the apk.

Kindly advice me in this regard.

Thanks

Nagendra.

Comment: yes you can use raw folder or direct from localstorage sdcard or usb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can put them in `/drawables/raw` folder and you can access them like mentioned in [Load html files from raw folder in web view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171316/load-html-files-from-raw-folder-in-web-view). If you talk about unzipping or even reverse engineering for that matter, the java code, layout files all can be reverse engineered, sometimes even if you obfuscate the code. I would suggest you to store all sensitive data on a servers and then get it on runtime in the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in drawable or values folder as well.