# Where put JavaScript file in Android Studio project?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, webview

`WebView` is being used with local `.html` file which in turn includes local `.js` files. Where to put `.html`, `.js` and probably other similar files in an `Android Studio` project so that IDE would show me these files and IDE plugins such as auto-complete would work?

Things I have tried:

1. `Assets` folder. Works but it is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9773191/2945917)

> as the assets cannot (and shouldn't) be updated once the app has been
> packaged and signed

but doesn't that mean that the next time I build `.apk` file and the application is beings installed the assets will be replaces with anything that was in the assets folder in the new `.apk` build?

2. `res/raw`. Got that idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15934525/2945917). Looks like it will work for `.html` files but not for `.js` as I am getting compilation error because of `.js` file: `'-' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore`
3. `/drawables/raw`. Does not seem to work at all although it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26879856/2945917). First thing - `Android Studio` does not even show these files if you put them in that directory (tried renaming to `/drawable/raw`, note not a plural name) so that is an issue for me even if compilation would succeed. Second - if I put `.html` and `.js` files in `drawable` I get: `The file name must end with .xml or .png`
4. Tried putting them in one of Java packages but could not get those files because it seems [Android Java can not access files like plain Java does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27790439/2945917).

Comment: Enlighten me. What are you trying to achieve by statically packaging html?

Comment: Is this supposed to be an offline app?

Comment: Implementing an offline map application with OpenLayers since no other free and acceptapble framework would give me the functionality I need.

Comment: I updated my previous comment. It's an offline application

Comment: What if you package the script files using webpack so you end up with a single bundle file, then put it inline into your HTML document? Also, as far as I'm concerned, "the assets cannot be updated" doesn't sound like a deal breaker. When you publish an update to your app, what's keeping you from also updating the HTML / JS assets before you build the updated version? I assume that statement was based on coming from an app that uses online HTML, which can of course be updated independently of the app.

Comment: Your suggestion with `webpack` might work. About the `assets`: it is my first `Android` application so I find the `assets` folder solution to be an issue only because it was said to be so in a couple of `stackoverflow` posts - other than that I have no issues with `assets` folder.